# Electrostatic energy of a distribution of charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, work

I read, in Gettys' *Physics*, that, if $N$ charges moves one by one from infinity to a certain point, i.e. the first charge $q_1$ moves from infinity to the arrival point $P$ while the other charges remain at infinity, then $q_2$ moves from infinity to $P$ while $q_1$ remains still, then $q_3$ moves from infinity to $P$ while $q_1$ and $q_2$ remain still, and so on, then, as I find easy to prove, the work done by the electric field generated by the charges that are already at $P$ on the arriving charges is$$\frac{1}{8\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\ne j}}^N\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}\quad\quad(1)$$where $r_{ij}$ is the distance separating $q_i$ from $q_j$.

Such work is obviously invariant under a change of order of arrival of the charges.

Is the work invariantly expressed by the formula $(1)$ even if the charges does not move one by one, but in general even if there is contemporaneity in their movements? If it is, how can it be proved?

---

***Remark***: let $I$ and $J$ be the points where the charges $q_i$ and $q_j$ are respectively found; I think that proving the invariancy of the formula $(1)$ is equivalent to proving that $\frac{1}{8\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\ne j}}^N\frac{q_iq_j}{\|\overrightarrow{IJ}(t_b)\|}-\frac{1}{8\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\ne j}}^N\frac{q_iq_j}{\|\overrightarrow{IJ}(t_a)\|}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \int_{t_a}^{t_b} \frac{q_iq_j}{\|\overrightarrow{IJ}(t)\|^3}\overrightarrow{JI}(t)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\overrightarrow{OI}(t)\text{ }dt$
for any paths parametrised by $\overrightarrow{OI}:[t_a,t_b]\to\mathbb{R}^3$, $I=1,\ldots,N$. Nevertheless, since, if the charges moves, the electric field is not conservative in general, I do not know how to proceed...

Comment: Consider a process wherein each charge is brought to its final position via some time dependent trajectory, i.e. $\vec{r}_i(t)$ for the $i^\text{th}$ charge. You can write the final potential energy in terms of those time dependent trajectories. Try it and see what happens. You'll figure this one out all by yourself. This is what you already tried, but think about what happens if you do it realllllyyyyy sloowwwwwllyyyyyy.

Comment: @DanielSank Thank you for your comment! I only realise that if the total displacement is the sum of successive displacements all done in one by one movements then the work done during each movement is $\frac{1}{8\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\ne j}}^N\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}(t_b)}-\frac{1}{8\pi\varepsilon_0}\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\ne j}}^N\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}(t_a)}$ where $t_a$ and $t_b$ respectively are the initial and final times...

Comment: ...and therefore the formula for the total work is in the same form. If I could mathematically prove that any work path integral for such displacement is the limit of a sum of integrals for one by one displacements I would understand that the formula (1) holds even for contemporary movements of the charges, but I really do not know how to mathematically prove that...